# autoLoginAfterAccountActivation doesn't seem to be working

Tags: craft3, login

In the midst of an upgrade from 2 > 3 (Commerce on top of that too).

When a user creates an account, it fires an 'Activate your account' email

That email goes through to `account/activation-success` and the account is verified and all is well. Almost.

On that template, we have `{{ currentUser }}` but in v3 - it's null because auto-login doesn't look to be functioning.

In `general.php` we've got:

```
'activateAccountSuccessPath' => 'account/activation-success',
'autoLoginAfterAccountActivation' => true,
```

Has something changed? We're on Craft 3.5.16 and Commerce 3.2.12

Comment: Did you find out if this was a craft issue or user error? I am encountering the same on a fresh install. Thanks